# Load data and save data in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Hello I am trying to create a GUI in Matlab. Using a push button I try to select .txt file an load it as a matrix. My only problem is that I can select the .txt file  but I cannot load it in the workspace. Here what I have done till now:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.txt', 'Select a MATLAB code file');
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('User selected Cancel')
else
   disp(['User selected ', fullfile(pathname, filename)])
end
```

fileID = fopen(fullfile(pathname, filename)); % Open the file

A = fread(fileID); % Read from the file

fclose(fileID); % Close the file

S = char(A)

Comment: `disp` won't load data anywhere, let alone in GUI. Whatelse have you tried?

Comment: Yes I know that. I have tried the load command(filename) but did not work.

Comment: Edit you question with that and show us the error/problem that might be popping up. First try to make it work in a script without GUI and once it does, you may post that code too.

Comment: I run the code to a .txt with values [1 2 3 4 5 6] and returns an A.mat having these values [49
    13
    10
    50
    13
    10
    51
    13
    10
    52
    13
    10
    53
    13
    10
    54]. Just do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the filename you can try opening it and reading from it using the functions:

```
fileID = fopen(fullfile(pathname, filename)); % Open the file
A = fread(fileID); % Read from the file
fclose(fileID); % Close the file
```

Unfortunately how to best parse the data from the `*.txt` file to a matrix depends on the file as well as your specific needs.

Comment: I try it with a single txt containing the numbers [1 2 3 4 5 6]. However I am not able to see my txt file as a mat file on my workspace.I do not have an error just not the result that I expected.

Comment: The data is probably being read in as ASCII values.  Try using `S = char(A)` to convert your ASCII values to a character array.

Comment: Thanks but still not. I have posted the code. If it is possible have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To load data into MATLAB from an ASCII (text) file you should use the `importdata` command. See here: [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)

Depending on whether you have delimiters (e.g., tab, comma) or hear lines in the text file, you would have to specify different input arguments to the command.